# Django inner join on same table

Tags: django, group-by, inner-join, annotate

Thanks in advance for any help.

I have an SQL query that a developer not so keen on Django is asking me to demonstrate working using the framework.

```
SELECT h.cuh_cur_code_inc, h.cuh_cur_code_out, h.cuh_rate, h.cuh_date
FROM
(
    SELECT cuh_cur_code_inc, cuh_cur_code_out, MAX(cuh_id) as cuh_id_max
    FROM cur_hist
    WHERE cuh_cur_code_out = 'GBP'
    GROUP BY cuh_cur_code_inc, cuh_cur_code_out
) latest
INNER JOIN cur_hist h ON latest.cuh_id_max = h.cuh_id


+------------------+------------------+----------+---------------------+
| cuh_cur_code_inc | cuh_cur_code_out | cuh_rate | cuh_date            |
+------------------+------------------+----------+---------------------+
| EUR              | GBP              |   0.8126 | 2012-12-03 06:00:28 |
| USD              | GBP              |   0.6241 | 2012-12-02 06:00:25 |
+------------------+------------------+----------+---------------------+
```

Above is an example results table. I can achieve the above result with 2 calls (that's not difficult obviously) but I cannot seem to recreate the inner join.

```
histories = CurHist.objects.filter(cuh_cur_code_out='GBP') \
                               .values('cuh_cur_code_inc', 'cuh_cur_code_out') \
                               .annotate(cuh_id_max=Max('cuh_id'))

histories = CurHist.objects.filter(cuh_id__in=[x['cuh_id_max'] for x in histories]).order_by('-cuh_rate')
```

The model looks like this:

```
class CurHist(models.Model):
    cuh_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    cuh_cur_code_inc = models.CharField(max_length=9)
    cuh_cur_code_out = models.CharField(max_length=9)
    cuh_rate = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    cuh_date = models.DateTimeField(
```

I am aware of Django's extra method on the object manager but am not sure in this case how I would go about using it. Is this even the correct approach to take or am I trying to fit a square peg through a circular hole?

Any help would be appreciated!